# Meaning of "NoReverseMatch" in Django

Tags: django

I'm learning Django, and I'm stuck on a "NoReverseMatch" error.  I'm trying to understand how to fix the error, and what the error actually means.  Django is trying find a pattern in the routes that is the reverse of the given url?

```
NoReverseMatch at /customers/3/

Reverse for 'customer' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customers/(?P<customer_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^customers/(?P<customer_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.customer, name='customer'),
]
```

[update]...this is apparently being triggered from the template:

```
  <form action="{% url 'customer' customer.id %}" method="post" class="form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% bootstrap_form form %}
      {% buttons %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
          </button>
      {% endbuttons %}
  </form>
```

...and the view code:

```
def customer(request, customer_id):
    c = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=customer_id)
    context = {'customer': customer}
    return render(request, 'customers/edit.html', context)
```

Comment: What action causes this error to arise ? When loading a page, when running something in the console ?

Comment: @OYRM updated to be more clear

Comment: Can you add your view code ?

Comment: @OYRM that was the ticket, I was failing to reference the customer object properly.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are passing `customer` from your view to the template context.

This section of the traceback

```
with arguments '('',)'
```

indicates that `customer.id` is evaluating to `''`, instead of an id like `3` as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

The error `NoReverseMatch` means that there's not found url pattern for the url you are trying. Check the value for `customer.id`. Post your `customer` view could be helpful.